# When I use flutter_screenutil or sizer package I am not able to declare "home". I am getting the error parameter "home" is not defined

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

This is my code of main dart file:

```
void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp());
}

class MaterialApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints){
        return OrientationBuilder(
          builder: (context, orientation){
            SizerUtil().init(constraints, orientation);
            return new MaterialApp(
              home: OpeningScreen()
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This the error I am getting:

```
The named parameter 'home' isn't defined.  Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'home'.
```

I have an OpeningScreen() class that renders the landing page UI of the App.
When I use "home" in flutter_screenutil also, same error came.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the ScreenUtil(). Problem is here

```
 class MaterialApp extends StatelessWidget
```

You can't use **MaterialApp** as a class name as it is **pre defined** in flutter libraries.
Try using some other name e.g class MyApp extends StatelessWidget

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: Size(360, 690),
      allowFontScaling: false,
      builder: () => MaterialApp(
      
        home: Testing(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```